# How to run SpeakerIdentApp, a MARF example?

Tags: java, jar

I've downloaded the bin files "SpeakerIdentApp-bin-0.3.0-devel-20060226.tar.bz2" [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/marf/files/).

I've extracted them and through the console I made:

```
java -jar SpeakerIdentApp.jar
```

The usage message appears saying how the command must be performed.

If I execute:

```
java -jar SpeakerIdentApp.jar --stats
```

it works. But if I execute:

```
java -jar SpeakerIdentApp.jar --ident lol.wav --raw
```

or

```
java -jar SpeakerIdentApp.jar --ident lol.wav
```

or

```
java -jar SpeakerIdentApp.jar --ident lol.wav -rar
```

it doesn't work.

So, how do I execute it?

I would like also to know how to make a java project on eclipse with the content of the jar's given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They say that you need to put options but that's incorrect.
Simply don't use options and will work!

Answer (score 1):

at first you  need a marf-version.jar and speakerIdentApple bundle and make sure your marf.jar ans spearindenrapple bundle in class library then just run it work  fine.